# Tools to Automate Amazon S3 backups from Windows Server

Tags: amazon-s3

In order to take regular backups, we want to compress and upload files from our Windows Server to Amazon S3 service.  Is there any freeware application that allows us to schedule regular backups?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your best bet is to use [Windows PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell).

This blog post describes how to automate SQL Server backups with PowerShell to Amazon S3:

- [Randoom: EC2 SQL Server backup strategies and tactics](http://friism.com/ec2-sql-server-backup-strategies-and-tactics)

Comment: Here is another one that uses 7Zip and AES Encryption for secure backups to Amazon S3: http://codeblog.theg2.net/2010/02/powershell-7-zip-amazon-s3-upload.html

Answer (score 8):

There is also a newer option that has become available in the meantime:

[Standalone Windows .EXE command line utility for Amazon S3 & EC2](http://s3.codeplex.com/)

It's a .Net command-line tool executable that provides S3 commands to work with the S3 directly or through batch scripts.

Comment: If you use this utility, do not forget to encrypt your backup.  Data on S3 is *not* encrypted, nor are data transfers within the AWS network unless explicitly over an SSL or SSH link.

Answer (score 2):

Another great tool is S3Sync from SprightlySoft (free & opensource - [S3Sync.zip](https://sites.google.com/site/jitbit/files/S3Sync.zip?attredirects=0&d=1)) - a command line tool for windows. It offers a "differential" sync of a folder, detecting all additions, deletions/file-changes etc.

Here's a detailed article on how to use it [Automating S3 backups on Windows](https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/214-automating-amazon-s3-backups-on-a-windows-server/)

Comment: The link to the above article has now moved to https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/214-automating-amazon-s3-backups-on-a-windows-server/

Comment: @A.Gneady woops, fixed the link. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

We do this under Linux with a shell script (batch file) that simply zips the required files and then calls s3cmd (from the Amazon command line tools) to put the zip file to an S3 bucket.  There's also some exit code (errorlevel) checking to ensure everything went well.

We schedule that script with cron.  You could do the same with windows [task scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614(VS.85).aspx).

If you need a command line capable ZIP utility, [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) is a good open source choice.

Comment: Any command line tools for windows? seems to be s3cmd is for linux

Comment: s3cmd works with Windows after installing Python.

Comment: s3cmd works,  but you should take a look at s3.codeplex.com its an exe that you can call from any language on windows.  
We follow the same route as yours execpt we share our /Backup directory on our linux server using webdav.  We backup from windows to webdav, and then the linux cron script uses s3cmd to push syncs to s3

Comment: @Frank: Cool.  It looks like zappan added a link to that, but I didn't notice until I saw your comment. Nice to know it's there.

Comment: @eric I have been playing with S3 quite a bit and now this is how we do it.  For backups we just use s3cmd on a linux server.  It works awesome.  We have a bash script that automatically syncs our /X/Backups directory to a bucket.  We also use apache webdav to open up /X/Backups on our network so that windows systems (using corbian backup) can create backups and store them there to be uploaded to s3.  Also loving Chilkat's asp / .net components.  They let us programatically upload user content to S3, which makes worrying about storage a thing of the past. MaxCDN in front of s3.

Comment: Unfortunately `s3cmd` error codes are not at all reliable. The version 1.1.0 from Ubuntu 14.04 Universe gives exit code of 0 if s3cmd fails to resolve the Amazon hosts, so you shouldn't trust it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [backup rubygem](https://github.com/meskyanichi/backup/).  It lets you define the backups declaratively, and then shells out to command-line tools to actually run them.  It's probably cross-platform enough.

Alternatively, yes; powershell can be made to do what you want with the AWS .NET SDK loaded - it's quite bare-bones compared to the ruby one, though; I've ended up with far more concise ruby-based scripts than powershell ones (and I'm reasonable at both approaches, I think), since the ruby sdk layers a nicer model over the top of each API.